# Lucene Solr - Multi Core vs Multiple Instance for Different Schema Documents

Tags: solr, lucene

I have performance concerns and wanted suggestions which work best for `Multi Core` or `Multi Instance(with different port)`?

My Case First:

> - Currently I am running Solr with multiple cores and its running OK. There is only one issue that sometime it throws "out of heap memory while processing facets fields", after which I have to restart the solr. ( To minimize the no. of restarts, I starts the Solr with high memory : java -Xms1000M -Xmx8000M -jar start.jar )
> - I have amazon EC2 instance with 8core-2.8GHtz /15GB Ram with optimized hard disk.
> - I have many database-tables(about 100) and have to create different schemas for each(leads to create different core).
> - Each table has millions of documents, with 7-9 indexed fields and 10-50 stored fields per document.
> - My web portals should handle very high traffic (currently I m having 10 request/second, may increase to 50-100/second). I know 'Solr' can handle that but it is just to inform you that I am concerned about every-smallest performance issue
> - Searching Solr by PHP and CURL in to specific core, so there is no problem of searching on different Solr instance also.

**Question:**

As per my knowledge **Solr handles one request at a time**. So I think if I create multiple instance of solr and starts those at different port, then my web portal can handle more request at a time. (if user search in different table).

*So, what you will suggest me? Multi Core in Single Solr Instance? or Multiple Instances with Single/Dual Core in each?*

*Is there any problem in having multiple Solr instances running at different ports?*

*NOTE:* Here, I can/may/will combine less-searched-core(s)/small-core(s) in one instance **AND** heavy-traffic-core(s) in separate instance **OR** two-three-heavy-traffic-core in one-instance etc. **Coz**, creating different Instances for each table(~100 here) will take too much hardware resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Solr can handle multiple requests at a time**.

I have tested it by running a long query [qTime=7203, approx. 7sec] and several small-queries-after the long-one [qTime=30], Solr responds for smaller queries first, even if they ran after the long-query.

**This point gives much reason in answer:** Use single solr instance with multiple core. Just assign High memory to JVM.

---

**Other Points:**

**1.** Each solr instance will require RAM, so running multiple instances will require more resources, which will be expensive. And if you are using `facets`, `sort fields` then you need to allocate more RAM to each instance.

As you can see in my case I need to start the solr with high memory(8GB). You can see a case for [Danish Web Archive](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceData), Which uses multiple instances and allocated 9GB RAM to each with cumulative 256GM total RAM.

**2.** You can run **multiple instances of solr on different PORTS** by using the command `java -Djetty.port=8984 -jar start.jar`. Everything ran ok BUT I got one problem.

While indexing it may give **"not enough memory error"** and then solr instance will be killed. So you need to start second instance with high memory, which will lead to more RAM requirement.

**3.** Solr Resource Requirement and Performance Problem can be understand [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems). According to this 64bit environment and 12GB RAM is recommended for good performance. Solr Optimization are explained [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors).

Comment: This is pretty interesting, is your Solr setup configured as SolrCloud or plain single Solr with multiple cores?

Comment: @perrohunter: Single Solr With Multiple Core.